# im getting correct time in the local system. but after uploading application in the server i'm getting incorrect datetime

Tags: c#, datetime

im getting incorrect time in the remote server.i'm getting the correct datetime in the local system.our server may be in other country, how to get correct datetime which is im getting in the local system.

Local application date time - `23/05/2018 06:40:20 PM`

time after deploy in server - `23/05/2018 09:10:20 AM`

timestamp - 2018-05-23T10:56:12.730Z

getting output

```
23/05/2018 09:10:20 AM
```

Expected Output

```
23/05/2018 06:40:20 PM
```

Code

```
string time = con.PayloadsUl.Timestamp.ToString();
onem2m.time = Convert.ToDateTime(time).ToString(string.Format("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"));
```

data type

```
public class onem2m {
    public string dataFrame{ get; set; }
    public string time { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect an output that starts with `MM` when you are explicitly passing `dd` as the beginning of the format?

Comment: im least bother about the mm in the starting , im looking for correct time which im not getting

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
string time = con.PayloadsUl.Timestamp.ToString();
DateTime utcdate = DateTime.ParseExact(time, "M/dd/yyyy 
                                           h:mm:ss tt",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    var istdate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcdate,
    TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time"));
```

Comment: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. my time value - 23/05/2018 12:20:57 +00:00

Answer (score -3):

Try Using `SimpleDateFormat` class and

```
TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST")
```

Comment: What `SimpleDateFormat`/`TimeZone` class? That does not exist on the .NET Framework.

Comment: @Camilo Seems to be a java answer to a C# question :-(

Comment: @john I imagined, but I don't know enough Java to point that out

Comment: Even if this were Java, use of the `SimpleDateFormat` class is strongly discouraged, that class is long outdated and notoriously troublesome. And you should never rely on a three letter time zone abbreviation like IST. You cannot know whether Java gives you Irish Summer Time, Israel Standard Time or India Standard Time.